# Two calendars being opened when click on datepicker

Tags: joomla, chronoforms

I am having an issue for which I can find no Solution. Once I click on a datepicker on this page two date picker panels are opened for them. It only happens on this page. So I know there must be some kind of conflict. Please advise if I should add the source code of the form on the following [page](http://www.royalmarang.com/request-a-proposal)

Comment: It seems ok to me. What browser are you using?

Comment: Hi there, Sorry I fixed the issue. I forgot to close this question. Thank you for wanting to assist though!

Comment: Then maybe you could share what caused your issue and how you fixed it.

Comment: Downvoted until I see the solution from the OP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chronoforms Has an issue with having multiple forms on a single page. I had an booking engine on the very same page and they conflicted. Once I removed the booking engine the form worked perfectly and I did not have the multiple datepicker issue anymore